# Need Thick Border on last row of the tablix without an extra row

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a report with two rows (One heading Row and a Detail Row). If I give Thick Border row in the bottom of the tablix then the thick border will come on each and every row of the Report. I have added extra column and give the top Border of that row as BOLD (1.5pt) and its comming in correct way.

But I need something without an extra row in the output(when exporting to excel). Please advice.

Comment: Possible answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-last-function Get the value of the last row using above then in the details row check if value - last row value and if so add the border.

Comment: Thanks for your quick turn around snowlockk...I have learned something new today.

Answer (score 5):

Select all of tablix.
click "bottom border" from the report borders toolbar

Comment: You should also mark the answer that solves your problem